# React-Routing getting 404 page using history.push()

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I need to open a sub-page of my news page on a click. At the moment I can open the new URL by using history.push, but it returns a 404 page.

I've tried to change history.push with Redirect, no luck. I don't think Redirect is the right option. I think my issue is related to the way I have set up the route.js file.

- Paths.js file:

```
export const PATHS = {
  NEWS: '/news',
  NEWS_SHOWS: type => `/news/last/${type}`
}
```

As you can see above, I need to pass type because each time I open the same component, I might call different content. `type` will add something like `/latest OR /newest OR /most-read`

- Route.js file:

```
<Switch>
    <UniqueRoute exact path={PATHS.NEWS} component={News} />    
</Swicth>
```

- Component with the button:

```
import React from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

import { PATHS } from '../../constants';
import Button, { VARIANTS as BUTTON_VARIANTS } from '../../components/Button';

const ViewMoreButton = ({ history, type }) => (
  <Button
    onClick={() => history.push(PATHS.NEWS_SHOWS(type))}
  />
);

export default withRouter(ViewMoreButton);
```

- On click, the page URL would be:

```
localhost:3000/news/last/latest 
OR
localhost:3000/news/last/newest
etc...
```

At the moment, I get 404 with any of those URLs above. an error when the page loads.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Um, of course you're getting a 404, the Route.js only contains one route (`/news`), and not any of the ones you want to navigate to (`/news/last/${type}`)

Comment: If I add <UniqueRoute exact path={PATHS. NEWS_SHOWS} component={NewsShows} /> it returns an error. Standard React error about str.slice. Can you suggest how Route.js and Paths.js should be configured?

Comment: Also expected as you're passing a function instead of the result of the function (String). I'll post a suggestion for Route.js in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have one route defined in Route.js, try:

```js
<Switch>
    <UniqueRoute exact path={PATHS.NEWS} component={News} /> 
    <UniqueRoute exact path={PATHS.NEWS_SHOWS('latest')} component={NewsShows} />   
    <UniqueRoute exact path={PATHS.NEWS_SHOWS('newest')} component={NewsShows} />   
    <UniqueRoute exact path={PATHS.NEWS_SHOWS('most-read')} component={NewsShows} />      
</Switch>
```

or, a bit more elegant if you want to easily extend with more types:

```js
<Switch>
    <UniqueRoute exact path={PATHS.NEWS} component={News} /> 
    {['latest', 'newest', 'most-read'].map(type => 
      <UniqueRoute exact path={PATHS.NEWS_SHOWS(type)} component={NewsShows} />
    )}     
</Switch>
```

Or, look into using [url params](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/url-params) instead specifying every type in your router:

```js
<Switch>
    <UniqueRoute exact path={PATHS.NEWS} component={News} /> 
    <Route path="/news/last/:type" component={NewsShows} />  
</Switch>
```

Would also suggest using react router's [Link](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/Link.md) instead of a button with an onclick=history.push hack:

```js
const ViewMoreButton = ({ history, type }) => (
  <Link to={PATHS.NEWS_SHOWS(type)}> link text </Link> 
);
```